# Compilation error: "The last statement in a 'do' construct must be an expression"

Tags: haskell, dining-philosopher

The following is my dining philosophers code and yields a compilation error saying "The last statement in a 'do' construct must be an expression: mVar2 <- newEmptyMVar mVar3" 
 Can Somebody help me fix this error and get this program working? thank you

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import System.Random

takefork :: Int -> forks -> IO ()
takefork n forks = takeMVar (forks!!n)

releasefork :: Int -> forks -> IO ()
releasefork n forks = putMVar (forks!!n)

philosopher :: [Int]
philosopher = [1,2,3,4,5]

forks :: [MVar] -> [Int]
forks = do
    takefork n ( philosopher - 1)
    threadDelay delay
    let delay = 100000
    takefork n philosopher
    putStrLn("Philosopher" ++ philosopher ++ "has started eating")
    releasefork n philosopher
    releasefork n ( philosopher - 1)
    ptStrLn ("Philosopher" ++ philosopher ++ "has stopped eating")
    forks

main :: IO ()
main = do
    mVar1 <- newEmptyMVar
    mVar2 <- newEmptyMVar
    mVar3 <- newEmptyMVar
    mVar4 <- newEmptyMVar
    mVar5 <- newEmptyMVar
    let mVar = [mVar1, mVar2, mVar3, mVar4, mVar5]
    sequence_ [ forkIO forks (mVar philosopher) ]
```

Comment: This doesn't compile for a number of reasons that have probably nothing to do with your problem, could you fix them? (For instance, "`16:14: Not in scope: 'n'`")

Comment: it is in scope. I don't understand why it yields not in scope for you though.

Comment: Well, no it isn't! `n` would need to be either defined as a global variable or as a function parameter to `forks`, neither is the case. And that's not the only problem. — Please do copy the program you're asking about _exactly_.

Comment: Well I don't understand why it has be done like that. In my program what I am doing is merely calling the functions I have defined inside forks and making it a recursive function. I feel like my major problem occurs while implementing the main.

Comment: In the line `takefork n ( philosopher - 1)`, where does the `n` come from? It isn't declared anywhere. Also, you are treating `philosopher` like a number, which it isn't. There are a lot of other issues with the code, as well.

Comment: oh now I see where you are coming from. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many problems with your code.

The error message you report indicates you are probably mixing spaces and tabs. Get rid of the tabs and use only spaces.

---

You are presumably writing this program in order to practice writing Haskell programs, not in order to run the program for fun and profit. So we don't want to simply give you a working Dining Philosophers implementation, we want to help you write *your* implementation.

I cannot tell from your code how you expect it to work.

I'm going to focus on the last line:

```
sequence_ [ forkIO forks (mVar philosopher) ]
```

`sequence_ :: [IO a] -> IO ()` --- give `sequence_` a list of i/o actions, and it (returns an i/o action that) performs each action in order. From the `[...]`, it looks like you are trying to give it a list, but with only one element. This is probably not what you mean.

`forkIO :: IO () -> IO ThreadID` --- give `forkIO` an i/o action, and it (returns an i/o action that) starts that i/o action running in a new thread, giving you the id of that thread.

There are two problems here:

- `forks` is a function, not an i/o action (it's not even a function that returns an i/o action, though you probably mean it to be)
- you give `forkIO` a second argunment (`(mVar philosopher)`), but it only takes one argument

`mVar philosopher` itself doesn't make any sense: `mVar :: [MVar a]` (it's a list of MVars, and I haven't worked out what type the MVars are supposed to contain) but you treat it like a function, passing it `philosopher` as an argument.

At this point a lightbulb blinks on above my head. You wish to call `forks` with parameters `mVar` and `philosopher`?

```
sequence_ [ forkIO (forks mVar philosopher) ]
```

We're still sequencing a single action though. Perhaps you wish to call `forks` with each element of `philosopher` in turn?

```
sequence_ $ map (\n -> forkIO (forks mVar n)) philosopher
```

We can simplify this to

```
mapM_ (\n -> forkIO (forks mVar n)) philosopher
```

This doesn't match up with the type you given `forks :: [MVar] -> [Int]`. But that's probably wrong, so you'll want to fix that function next.

Comment: The code does indeed contain tabs, as can be seen if you "edit" the post and select some whitespace.

Comment: yea I have noticed that and have fixed the tabs issue. What I am trying to do is use the numbers inside the philosopher list at `takefork n (philosopher - 1)` I am trying to better understand how to use the number.

Comment: That was really helpful. Thanks a lot. At this point I realize that the number arguments provided in `forks :: [MVar] -> [Int]` doesn't match the arguments required. I am assuming that the above function should be returning an IO action. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you

Comment: No, that's right. I expect you want `forks :: [MVar] -> Int -> IO ()`.

Comment: I am having trouble with defining `n`. Inside the `forks` function, when declaring the variable `n`, what should it be declared as `let n =` ?

Comment: Shouldn't `n` should be the second parameter to `forks`? So the definition of `forks` should start `forks mVar n = do`.

Comment: I changed the code accordingly, changing the parameters for the `forks` function and starting it the above stated way. I have been dealing with this error `'MVar' is not applied to enough type arguments Expected kind '*', but 'MVar' has kind '* -> *' In the type signature for 'forks' : forks :: [MVar] -> Int -> IO ()` Not sure what it means

Comment: Sorry; should probably be `forks :: [MVar ()] -> Int -> IO ()`. `MVar` is not a type. `MVar Int`, `MVar String`, `MVar Double` etc are types. The type parameter specifies the type of data that is stored in the MVar.

Comment: In the above code `putStrLn("Philosopher" ++ philosopher ++ "has started eating")` this part expects a char type while the actual type is Int. why is that?

Comment: `++` is for concatenating lists. `String` is just an alias for `[Char]`. `philosopher :: [Int]`. So you are trying to concatenate lists of different types. Use `show philosopher` instead of `philosopher`. (Also, you probably want to show n, not philosopher, but try it with philosopher first to see why.)

Comment: `show philosopher` works. I assumed that I can use philosopher or n, because the value would have been same. I have couple errors being yielded, one would be that in `takefork n forks = takeMVar (forks!!n)` it couldn't match type `forks` with `[MVar()]` and similarly with `releasefork` it couldn't match expected type `IO()` with actual type `a0 -> IO ()` why is this happening? thanks a lot @dave4420 for all the help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: In your type signatures for `takefork` and `releasefork` you have the type variable `forks`. It is unrestricted so means "any type". It should be the specific type mentioned in the error message. Additionally in `releasefork`, `putMVar` requires an additional argument (the value to place inside the MVar).

Comment: @dave4420 well I tried specifying the type for `forks` by doing this `type forks = [MVar()]` but I get an error saying `Malformed head of type or class declaration` What does this mean?

Comment: @BobbyPeddireddy Lower case is for variables and type variables. Types and type aliases have to start with a capital letter. But I don't think you need to make a type alias: replace the type signature for `takefork` with `takefork :: Int -> [MVar ()] -> IO ()` and similarly for `releasefork`.

Comment: well I did that, but I feel like I am missing an argument in `releasefork n forks = putMVar (forks!!n)`

Comment: Yes, `putMVar` requires an additional argument (the value to place inside the MVar).

Comment: This is where I am having trouble with. I understand that when we do `takeMVar` a value of MVar is taken, isn't the same value being placed inside MVar when `putMVar` is performed? I don't know why, I am getting confused for some reason.

Comment: No. `takeMVar` waits for the mvar to contain a value, then it removes that value from the mvar and returns it to you. You then ignore this value. Meanwhile, `putMVar` waits for the mvar to be empty, then it places the value you give it into the mvar. `releasefork n forks = putMVar (forks!!n) ()`.

Comment: @dave4420 when `takefork` is called, with `(philosopher - 1)` as the argument, the program doesn't let us do that as it expects MVar() but we provided an Int. Should I change the type for philosopher then?

Comment: @BobbyPeddireddy You have changed enough of your program that it is probably best to start a new top-level question and include your current code there.